# How to make this slider work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to develop my web programming skills. Now, I am trying to make auto picture slider. I am trying to apply one, from website but unfortunately it does not work:

### JS code

```
$("#home_pic > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#home_pic > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#home_pic');
},  3000);
```

### CSS code

```
#home_pic img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7C7063;
}
```

### HTML code

```
<div id="home_pic">
            <div><img src="pic0.png"></div>
            <div><img src="pic1.png"></div>
        </div> <!--end of home_pic-->
```

### Problem

Well, pictures seems to change but they appear one below another.
[descpription problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvJyo.png)

Comment: i recommend to you use  Js cycle plugin

Comment: Question seems a little vague, what are you trying to achieve exactly, is it simply a layout issue?

Comment: I think you may just be missing a reference to JQuery.

Comment: also next time use js fiddle to post the example.. its easier to work with for us to give an answer and for you to read it

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the javascript once the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#home_pic > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#home_pic');
    },  3000);
});
```

See this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxt4nh5q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8g3z9qL/). I have changed your code like this :

**JS**

```
$("#home_pic > img:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#home_pic > img:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#home_pic');
},  3000);
```

**HTML**

```
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="home_pic">
    <img id="1" src="http://image.sportsmansguide.com/adimgs/l/1/145827_ts.jpg"> 
    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/net-clipart-FISHING_NET.jpg">
</div> <!--end of home_pic-->
```

**CSS**

```
#home_pic img {
    position:absolute;/* this is for the images to be overlayered for info search about position:absolute */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #7C7063;
}
```